# Compare probability estimates of two classifiers

Tags: classification, ensemble-modeling

Consider two binary classifiers A and B. Suppose that both A and B are predicting the same target, but that A is trained on a subset of the data for which a different set of features is available than for B. Suppose further that A and B output probability esitmates and that for a set of mixed input types (some with features that A can accept, others for B) I need to rank them by probability of being positive.

Perhaps (and this is completely fabricated) I'm trying to predict early mortality of lions and tigers in a zoo. Different features are available for early lion mortality than for early tiger mortality. However, I ultimately will need to order all of the big cats, (among both lions AND tigers) by likelihood of early mortality.

My ideas so far:

- Train a meta-estimator that accepts the input type (belonging to A or B) and the scores from A and B. I'm thinking xgboost or another tree-based regressor.
- Attempt to directly and monotonically transform the probability estimates from A and B so as to 'bring them into alignment' in such a way as to maximize the cross-validated AUC. This seems to be similar to the first option.

Other information:
 In my actual application there is class imbalance, and the class imbalance varies between A type datapoints and B type datapoints. Precision TPR/(TPR+FPR) is most important in a business context.

Comment: Your first idea is quite similar to [stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking). Typically you want to use a linear model as the meta estimator rather than XGBoost or whatever else due to the simplicity of the data.

Comment: @timeleathart The issue here is that for any single data point, either a prediction from model A is available, or a prediction from model B, but not both. Thus it is different from usual applications of stacking.

Comment: You seem to assume that the probability for A are somehow different that the probabilities for B. To me they are both probabilities and you can compare them directly without any transformation or meta-estimator.

Comment: @Pieter I fear that they may not be comparable, as probability estimates are sometimes only useful for ranking purposes, and can't to be taken too literally. However, It may be the case that direct comparison is possible in my application.